# Automation of Outlier Detection

Tags: python, algorithm, statistics, outliers

I am working on a problem, i.e. automation of outlier detection. For that, I need an algorithm to detect the outliers.

I read about z score and inter-quantile range. But z score works only for normally distributed data. And am not sure about the inter-quantile range if it works for every kind of data (even if it follows Gaussian distribution, Poisson distribution). I read about DBSCAN as well but don't know the credibility of this method.

Can anyone suggest some algorithm or some package in Python which I can use for automation of outlier detection?

I am looking more for some algorithm, or even a research paper would be fine, which I can code in Python later.

For reference, below is one of the examples of the data in which I have to find outlier.

```
month Units Sold
1     23178.78
2     23547.41
3     17720.51
4     25837.56
5     20375.98
6     16260.64
7     22881.59
8     25202.29
9     17255.29
10    20495.58
11    21253.27
12    20145.73
```

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn has quite a lot of algorithms for outlier detection. For example, you have Isolation Forest and One-class SVMs.

Here's a [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html) to some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I am working on the Outlier Detection (OD) tools topic as well.
In my experience, to do outlier detection, you may need to define your problem first.

1. What is your desired outlier?
2. From the feature engineering viewpoint, how many features do you want to measure?
   One Dimension is quite simple; 2 or N features are totally different questions.
3. How would you like to show your OD result? 1 or 2 Dimensions is easy; 3 or more dimensions should be a big challenge.
4. What is the feature datatype, numerical or categorical data? For categorical data, you might convert them to dummy factors in the beginning.

Regarding the Outlier detection algorithm, I think you can choose based on your data.

- **For 1 dimension, `Z-score` (from Scipy) or `Mad()` mode is OK.** Though data is not a normal distribution, but the two-mode could be easy for the explanation. You can use the more complicated algorithms and spend more time explaining why they are calculated as outliers.  The `Z-score` method is sensitive to extreme outliers. The Mad method is more robust in such cases.
- For 2 or more dimensions, my favorite `Isolated Forest` is fast speed(se) and acceptable accuracy(88%~89%) for a large dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using some unsupervised outlier detection like XBOS, HBOS, IsolationForest:

```py
#create the dataframe
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = { 
        'month':      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
        'Units_Sold': [23178.78,  23547.41,17720.51,25837.56,20375.98,16260.64,22881.59 ,25202.29 ,17255.29 ,20495.58,21253.27,20145.73]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

#apply XBOS from this [Github](https://github.com/Kanatoko/XBOS-anomaly-detection)

from xbos import XBOS

xbos = XBOS(n_clusters=3)
result = xbos.fit_predict(df)
for i in result:
    print(round(i,2))
#results
#-0.74, -0.74, -0.94, -0.74, -0.81, -1.12, -0.91, -0.91, -1.03, -0.9, -0.9, -0.9
#                                     ^^^^                 ^^^^
#include results in dataframe
df['outlier_score']= result
df

#Visualization of outliers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

OD = df.query('outlier_score < -1')
plt.scatter(df.month, df.Units_Sold)
# set x-axis label and specific size
plt.xlabel('month',size=16)
# set y-axis label and specific size
plt.ylabel('Units_Sold',size=16)
plt.title('Visulization of unsupervised outlier Detection',size=14)
plt.scatter(OD.month, OD.Units_Sold, color="red")
```

The anomalous points are highlighted with red colors:
[image: img]